# questions on Spring @Autowired and Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I had some questions.

1. In which case `@Autowired` is not preferable?
2. In which scenario, we have to prefer `Spring-JDBC` than `Spring-Hibernate`?
3. What happens if we `autowire` all the objects?

Please help me on this questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. In which case @Autowired is not preferable?**

Autowiring is all about simplifying dependency injections. It may seems to be easy and lucrative at first but later you will realize that it is not maintainable in big real-life projects.

Default Autowiring in Spring is `by-Type`. I do not prefer it when I have more than one instance of any particular class and I have to force Spring to resolve the injections `by-Name` and have to use additional `@Qualifier`. I prefer going it with JAVAX `@Resource` in such cases.

Also, sometimes you might face a situation where you have to create and inject beans based on the properties/arguments. In such cases `@Autowired` might not work and you might have to opt for XML based configuration.

**2. In which scenario, we have to prefer Spring-JDBC than Spring-Hibernate?**

The choice of selection between JDBC vs Hibernate completely depends on your project and how well you think you can accommodate something like Hibernate. Both these implementations are very fast indeed. Both of these have their own advantages and disadvantages.

Using `Spring's JDBCTemplate` will be a bit easier as it is just a wrapper around the native JDBC itself. The only thing here is that you might end up in writing thousands of lines of code which can be really hard to maintain once your project starts growing.

Using `Hibernate` will result in a much cleaner and simpler code which is easy to maintain but the overhead here can be to learn Hibernate and think in a certain way to make it fit to your project.

**3. What happens if we autowire all the objects?**

It depends on your project needs. `@Autowire` is just used to inject the dependencies. Sometimes there is a situation where we encounter more than one instance of any particular class and in such cases to avoid using `@Qualifier` with `@Autowired` to remove the ambiguity you have a choice to replace the two annotations with a single annotation with `@Resource`.

Also, sometimes you'll find it better to inject the dependency beans via XML based configuration rather than using `@Autowired`.

There is no harm if you are Autowiring all your classes. As I said before it completely depends on your project needs.

Comment: Nearly any bean configuration that can be done in XML can be done more simply in JavaConfig.

Answer (score -2):

This is very general questions and you need to understand the basics of spring

1. @Autowire is annotation that can be used only on spring beans that you want to inject
2. If you use hibernate than you will need spring hibernate, if you use regular jdbc queries you will need spring jdbc
3. Like in section one, you can use autowire only on spring beans. Nothing will happen just will be a bad design :)